# ld: framework not found AFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: swift, ios7, xcode6, cocoapods

In my project I got cocoapod installed. Here is the structure of Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'TempWorkspace'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'proj1' do

    pod 'ApplicationInsights', '1.0-beta.4'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'Reachability'

end

target 'proj1Tests' do

end

target 'proj1UITests' do

end
```

In this, ApplicationInsights and GoogleAnalytics pod are not creating any issues. But if I add any pod except these 2 in this file, this is giving me following error

"ld: framework not found AFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Its not just about AFNetworking only if I write any other pod name also then also it is giving me same error with that pod name.

I tried looking for pod limitations but not it has not given me anything relevant.

If somebody has any idea please tell me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The whole issue was related to my project architecture only. SO now I have changed my project architecture. So for now  I have solved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I hope it will help someone with a similar problem with Pods, this answer worked for me on XCode 8:

1. Delete all your Podfiles from the pods folder (Pods folder should
   be empty)
2. Delete the xcworkspace file
3. run pod install
4. Change **Build Active Architectures Only** to **NO** for your target
   and for all your pods (Click on Pods project and then on each single
   Pod)
5. Add $(inherited) to the **Framework Search Path** setting of
   your target

I run into this problem because I was trying to install the latest Atlas pod which is implicitly installing the latest LayerKit pod and a reference to a framework was missing. For those with a similar problem remember to add use_frameworks! to your podfile.

Answer (score 2):

That same exact problem happened to me. The problem was that I was opening the .xcodeproj file instead of the .xcworkspace file. Once I opened the workspace file all my build errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems twice. I only use AFNetworking 3.0.4 or 3.1.0.
The method I handled with is to delete all the files:
 podFile files, the Podfile.lock file, xcworkspace, the 'Copy Pods Resources' and 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' in Build phases of targets.
After deleting all these, I write the file of podFile and pod install. the problem is solved.